# Interpreting a curve val_loss and loss in keras after training a model ; help

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras

I need some  help in Interpreting a curve val_loss and loss in keras after training a model

These are the learning curves:
[image: after 100 epoch of training]

Answer (score 1):

The training loss decreases while the validation loss increases, which is a clear sign of **overfitting**. This means that your model is too specific to the training dataset and do not generalize to the testing dataset. To solve that problem you can decrease the complexity of the model or add regularization.